# Why is my program crashing every time when i try to replace text in a file?

Tags: python, client, minecraft

I am using windows 10 and Python 3.9.0.
I am trying to make a legit Minecraft client in Python.
It would be like an auto-walk, auto-sprint and that stuff.
I have a file called module_state which looks like this:

```
walk = false
sprint = false
sneak = false
jump = false
auto_place = false
auto_hit = false
spam = false
```

And it works like this:
You launch a file called fim_client.py.
When you do that it loads everything neede and opens a custom shell which looks like this:

```
Fim Client >
```

And it also launches a file called `fim_client_reader.pyw` that reads the `module_state.md` and executes every module which has statement "True".
But every time i call function that replaces the text in the file it crashes.
Why?

Code:
fim_client.py:

```
import time
import os
f = open('module_state.md')
def replacedatafile(f, txttf, txttr):
    filedata = f.read()
        

    newdata = filedata.replace(txttf, txttr)

    
    f.write(newdata)
def return_cmd(dinput, f):
    if dinput == 'help':
        print('List of commands:')
        print('Walk')
        print('Sprint')
        print('Jump')
    elif dinput == 'sprint':
        print('sprint enabled')
        replacedatafile(f, "sprint = false", "sprint = true")
        os.system('pause')
        
NULL = 'pause'
dinput = 'dump'
intest = '.'
print('Fim Client alpha testing')
print('Using python build 3.9.0')
print('Installing librarys...')
time.sleep(3)
print('Running module.test...')
os.system('title Fim Client alpha testing')
time.sleep(2.4)
print(''' 










 








Welcome to Fim Client alpha testing!


Type "help" for a list of commands.
''')
os.system('python fim_client_reader_.pyw')
while True:
    dinput = input('Fim Client >')
    return_cmd(dinput, f)
```

fim_client_reader.pyw:

```
################# IMPORT #################################
import os
import subprocess

################ DECLARE VARIABLES ######################################
f = open('module_state.md')
line = 'dum'
walk = False
sprint = False
sneak = False
jump = False
########################################## MAIN #################################
for i in range(7):
    line = f.readline(i)
    if line == 'sprint = True':
        sprint = True
```

EDIT:

it returns an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gusta\coding\MINECRAFT______UYUIK\Client\fim_client.py", line 61, in <module>
    return_cmd(dinput, f)
  File "C:\Users\gusta\coding\MINECRAFT______UYUIK\Client\fim_client.py", line 20, in return_cmd
    replacedatafile(f, "sprint = false", "sprint = true")
  File "C:\Users\gusta\coding\MINECRAFT______UYUIK\Client\fim_client.py", line 11, in replacedatafile
    f.write(newdata)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

EDIT 2:

i tryed to replace `module_state.md` with `module_state.txt` but error is the same.

Comment: What do you mean by "it crashes"? *Exactly* what happens - do you see an exception traceback? If you do, [show the full traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough). Does it get stuck in an infinite loop? Does your computer BSOD? Something else? We can only help you figure out a problem if we understand what the problem is.

Comment: Also, please consider that if you have questions at this level and you aren't able to sort them out yourself, the task you describe is probably well beyond your current abilities.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel im talking about an external client that would be just a auto "w" presser and stuff. not like scaffold and no c++ included. no dll's no injectors and not that stuff.